# How to extract audio from a website

Tags: javascript, audio, web

I'm trying to download the audio file for the background music running on this site: http://middle-earth.thehobbit.com/map

I was expecting to find it under something like 'resources' with Chrome developer tools but no luck.

Is there some kind of javascript reference to the audio files?

Thanks in advance,

Will

Answer (score 0):

You can't access music resources through the console, unless it's embedded with HTML5's [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element.

However, you can record any sound played by your computer, using softwares like [Total Recorder](http://www.totalrecorder.com/), and save it to a sound file.